# AJAX call - name of view being added to URL? Results in 404 not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I feel like this must be something stupid I'm overlooking...I have a bunch of other AJAX calls in this file to the same controller that work fine, and I just can't see what is different about this one!

The url should be:

```
https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/nefin-xana/data/ajax_deleteTableRun
```

(where Data.php is the name of the controller)

BUT I keep getting the error:

```
POST https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/nefin-xana/program_overview/data/ajax_deleteTableRun 404 (Not Found)
```

The name of the view I'm on when ajax_deleteTableRun is called is program_overview.  Somehow this is getting added to the URL of the AJAX call?

```
function deleteTableRun(runId) {
    
    posturl='data/ajax_deleteTableRun';
    var data= {};
    data['runId']=runId;

  $.ajax({
            url: posturl,
            data: data,
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });    
}
```

In the Data controller:

```
public function ajax_deleteTableRun() {
    $postData=$this->input->post();
    $runId=$postData['runId'];
    $this->manage_model->delete_table_run($runId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL that is calling this ajax is

```
https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/nefin-xana/program_overview
```

and your code uses a relative URL

```
posturl='data/ajax_deleteTableRun';
```

Therefore, the JS is rightly appending the relative URL to the original URL.

Instead, consider using absolute URLs

```
posturl='/data/ajax_deleteTableRun';
```

Comment: hm, posturl='/data/ajax_deleteTableRun'; gave me a 404 not found also.  But you gave me an idea and I just wrote out the entire thing var posturl = baseURL + "data/ajax_deleteTableRun/"; and that worked!